# image and video compression

Tags: image-compression

What are similar compressors to the RAR algorithm?
I'm interested in compressing videos (for example, avi) and images (for example, jpg)

Winrar reduced an avi video (1 frame/sec) to .88% of it's original size (i.e. it was 49.8MB, and it went down to 442KB) 
It finished the compression in less than 4 seconds.

So, I'm looking to a similar (open) algorithm. I don't care about decompression time.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing "already compressed" formats are meaningless. Because, you can't get anything further. Even some archivers refuse to compress such files and stores as it is. If you really need to compress image and video files you need to "recompress" them. It's not meant to simply convert file format. I mean decode image or video file to some extent (not require to fully decoding), and apply your specific models instead of formats' model with a stronger entropy coder. There are several good attempts for such usages. Here is a few list:

1. [PackJPG](http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/): Open source and fast performer JPEG recompressor.
2. [Dell's Experimental MPEG1 and MPEG2 Compressor](http://encode.ru/threads/1111-Ocarina-s-MPEG1-and-MPEG2-video-compressor): Closed source and proprietry. But, you can at least test that experimental compressor strength.
3. [Precomp](http://schnaader.info/precomp.php): Closed source free software (but, it'll be open in near future). It recompress GIF, BZIP2, JPEG (with PackJPG) and Deflate (only generated with ZLIB library) streams.

Note that recompression is usually very time consuming process. Because, you have to ensure bit-identical restoration. Some programs even check every possible parameter to ensure stability (like Precomp). Also, their models have to be more and more complex to gain something negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Compressed formats like (jpg) can't really be compressed anymore since they have reached entropy; however, uncompressed formats like bmp, wav, and avi can.

Take a look at [LZMA](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)